# Installing java on Eclipse C/C++ Developers IDE (Kepler)?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I already have Eclipse Installed for C/C++ Prgorams. I have the Kepler Service Release 1.
I am planning to learn Android App Development so I need java, so is there a way to install java on this version? I don't want to do it manually like going on the website and downloading another eclipser. Is there a plugin for java?
If so can someone guide me through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it should be same as installing a plugin. So go to install new software menu. 
Then select the eclipse update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler and in the programming languages section select java development tools. You can also search it using the search bar.

Comment: There is also the small matter of installing the JDK, which all the answers, including this one, conveniently ignore.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I know You can update it on your current eclipse. Go to help on eclipse and click updates

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates

But there is a painful problem with update it. If I were you I would either use netbeans or re-install eclipse. Either one is going to be a easier solution than update.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answeres say, you should be able to update it. But I made the experience that updating something to eclipse can be really tricky. You will also need the Android stuff.  You can download eclipse with the Android SDK here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?utm_source=weibolife